# Is any of my data within a date range in February?

Tags: conditional, syntax, date

I am trying to see if a particular date range has any values in February. I tried using a range in an IF statement with 2 conditions (see below). I am getting a syntax error. Here is what I'm trying:

```
=datedif((and([RevStart]>01/31/2017,[RevStart]<03/01/2017),[GMI Effort],"-")
```

Where GMI Effort is a number and I've set the result to be viewed as a number.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Reformat with linebreaks and indentations, and you can spot your typo at line 2

```
=DATEDIF(
           (   
             AND(  [RevStart]>01/31/2017 
                  ,[RevStart]<03/01/2017
                )
            , [GMI Effort]
            , "-"
           )
```

also note that `"-"` is not a valid DateDif Unit notation

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1